# Backing Up SQL Database In SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent-job

I created a job to backup my SQL Database, just I am not sure if it is working correctly. In SQL Server 7 when it does a backup you get the mdf, and log files. The file that was backed up doesn't have an extension.

BACKUP DATABASE [TIMECLOCK] TO DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.CIPHERPOS\MSSQL\Backup\TCBU' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'TIMECLOCK', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'TIMECLOCK' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'TIMECLOCK' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''TIMECLOCK'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.CIPHERPOS\MSSQL\Backup\TCBU' WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND
GO

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Restore failed for Server 'POSWIN2K8\CIPHERPOS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1539+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: File "TIMECLOCK" cannot be restored over the existing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.CIPHERPOS\MSSQL\DATA\TIMECLOCK.mdf". Reissue the RESTORE statement using WITH REPLACE to overwrite pre-existing files, or WITH MOVE to identify an alternate location. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1+((KJ_RTM).100402-1539+)&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Well, what does the `BACKUP DATABASE` command in your job look like? You have to tell it the filename (including the extension). In SQL Server 7.0 it sounds like you weren't taking a real backup, just backup up the .mdf and .ldf files - that's not a proper backup.

Comment: Also, SQL Server doesn't really care what extension you use. `BACKUP DATABASE msdb TO DISK = 'C:\users\msdb.floobernuggets' WITH COPY_ONLY;` will work just fine, as will restoring it. However it is good practice to use `.BAK` for full backups and `.TRN` for log backups.

Comment: I will edit my post with the command

Comment: So change `TCBU'` to `TCBU.bak'`. Your current command tells it to save as a file called `TCBU` with no extension because, well, you didn't include an extension.

Comment: @AaronBertrand will and how will I be able to restore the TCBU.bak to SQL Manager? Will this work by right clicking on databases and clicking restore? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No, don't use Management Studio's flaky and inflexible UI. Please learn the [`RESTORE` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(SQL.105).aspx).

Comment: Wow... I have used the management studio in the past to restore backup databases. I tried to restore the database with the .bak file and I got this error message: that I reposted in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to delete the .mdf .ldf and .ndf database files from the folder before I could restore the backup. The backup restored just fine after that.

Comment: @HelloW I am glad to hear it